# Electric Garage Heater Installation

Tags: electrical, heater

I've installed 6awg copper wire to a junction box for a future electric garage heater.  The heater will eventually hang from the ceiling approximately 4-6 feet in front of the junction box.  (See photo below)  This is on a 60 amp 240v breaker.  Initially I was planning to install a 10,000 watt heater.  However, I now plan to downsize the heater to 7500 watts.  I realize I'll need to downsize the breaker to 40 amps.  Two questions:

1. Is it safe to use the existing 6 AWG copper with a 40 amp breaker assuming a 7500 watt heater?

2. Considering the above described downsize, is it safe to run an 8 AWG appliance whip from the junction box to the heater?

[image]

Comment: Also: [Can different gauges of wire be used on the same circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/128883/can-different-gauges-of-wire-be-used-on-the-same-circuit)

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Any segment of the circuit can use larger wire than is required for the load and breaker.  7500W is a good size as it just fits under the 7680W limit of a 40A circuit.  (40A x 80% x 240V).