# Electric Garage Heater

Tags: electrical

I've installed 6awg copper wire to a junction box for a future electric garage heater. The heater will eventually hang from the ceiling approximately 4-6 feet in front of the junction box. (See photo below) This is on a 60 amp 240v breaker. Initially I was planning to install a 10,000 watt heater. However, I now plan to downsize the heater to 7500 watts. I realize I'll need to downsize the breaker to 40 amps. Two questions:

1). Is it safe to use the existing 6 awg copper with a 40 amp breaker assuming a 7500 watt heater?

2). Considering the above described downsize, is it safe to run an 8 awg appliance whip from the junction box to the heater? Thank you.

Comment: Code mentions the minimum gauge wire to be used.  Larger gauges are fine and recommended for long distances.  Most breakers/switches will be made to accept one or two larger sizes.  You cannot use a smaller gauge wire than listed for that circuits amps.  Since 8 gauge is for 40 amps is okay to be used.   Should not ask the same question twice.  Edit your first with new information or go with the suggestions.

Comment: [You asked this already](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/266142/electric-garage-heater-installation)

Comment: Thank you.  This was my understanding as well.  Sorry for the redundant question.  I'm very new to this blog and my first question was "closed" because it was deemed a duplicate question.  However, when I viewed the proposed suggestions they did not completely answer my question.  Anyway, thanks just as well.

Comment: "Blog" has a very specific meaning. This ain't that. :) You should've commented on the first question to explain what was left wanting in the linked duplicate. We could've helped you there.

Comment: Look.  I explained I'm new to this.  I signed up today, and this is my first question ever posted.  I'm surprised how critical you are when I simply asked a very straight forward question seeking some seemingly simple advice.  Maybe stick to the content of the question and don't be so concerned about what this site is, and the way I'm asking a question.

Comment: Except you copy-pasted the original question *word for word* but without the picture.  That's not an act of *clarification*.  That's an act of *rebellion* done deliberately to spite admins and show disrespect for the forum. You knew perfectly well it would get moderated before you even hit "post".  What's up with that?  Doesn't sound like you're dealing in good faith.

Comment: Look. I sincerely duplicated it word for word with no disrespect for anyone.  I simply made an honest mistake.  At the top of the page it indicated it "has been closed".  I did not see the question and I thought it was deleted.  I realize now that this is not the case because after learning more about this site I was able to navigate back to it.  By the way Harper, your comment on the original question was helpful, thanks for that.  Also, "rebellion" is very over stated.  I know nothing about this site, how it runs, what is meant by "get moderated" nor do I show any spite towards admins.

Comment: Oh and by the way I meant to attach the pic to this post as well but again, I'm a newbie.  It seems like all who have commented are more concerned about how a question is submitted and proper etiquette without any lenience for the new guy.  Stick to the content of the question.

Comment: Steve is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering. Check out our Code of Conduct.